# Error when trying to connect to PostgreSQL database

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, heroku, psql

So I have a PostgreSQL database running through Heroku and I can connect to it on my mac terminal using

```
$ heroku pg:psql
```

It works perfectly fine on my home network, but when I try to run this command on my university network I am getting this error

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "bla bla bla" (bla bla bla) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port bla bla?
```

I have changed `listen_addresses = 'local'` to `listen_addresses = '*'` in the *postgresql.conf* file and added `host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` the *pg_hba.conf* file. I have also checked the credentials like host and port number and they are correct.

It's still not working.

What can I do to ensure the database can be accessed on all networks?

Comment: [`pg:psql`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql) is for connecting to your _remote_ database. Why would changing anything in your local `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` affect it? Your university may have a network policy in place that prevents this connection from working.

Comment: Pretty new to this but yes I think that is the case. @Chris although I cannot access my database through pg:psql, can users on my website still submit forms and add to it through the university wifi? (not sure if this is a silly question)

Comment: Yes, users will still be able to use your site on the university wifi, submitting forms that will cause database changes to occur. (It's technically possible that the university would block that, but we're talking about regular web traffic at this point. If you can browse other sites you shouldn't have any trouble using your Heroku-hosted site.) Why don't you try it out yourself?